# Python: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes

I keep getting this error(Detailed in title) when trying to run some code to perform ranked retrieval of terms in a document.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-93d0dd115e4c> in <module>()
----> 1 query_RR(postings,'england played well')

<ipython-input-21-647764dfc7e2> in query_RR(postings, qtext)
      7         for w in words:
      8             tf = math.log10(words.count(w))
----> 9             df = len(postings[w].values())
     10             idf = math.log10(N/df)
     11             query_weights[w] = tf * idf

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Here is the function where the error occurs:

```
    def query_RR(postings, qtext):
    words = tokenize(qtext)
    query_weights = {}
    doc_scores = {}
    for docID in range(N):
        score = 0
        for w in words:
            tf = math.log10(words.count(w))
            df = len(postings[w].values())
            idf = math.log10(N/df)
            query_weights[w] = tf * idf
        for w in words:
            if w in postings:
                score += query_weights[w] + postings[w].keys()
        doc_scores[docID] = score
    res = heapq.nlargest(10,doc_scores)
    return res
```

The function that is used before which creates postings for query_RR is:

```
def indextextfiles_RR(path):
postings={}
for docID in range(N):
    s = readfile(path, docID)
    words = tokenize(s)
    for w in words:
        if w!='':
          postings.setdefault(w,set()).add(docID)
return postings
```

I am so confused and fairly new to Python

Comment: Because postings contains sets, and sets don't have a values method.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail or have some code to display.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what else to add. `set().values()` is the [mre], and you can look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset.

Comment: Thanks for your help @jonrsharpe I figured it out, just me not looking properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `postings[w]` seems to be a set.  Set does not have a function `.values()`, but if you want to get the number of items in a set you can just use `len()` on it.  For you, that would be `len(postings[w])`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all sorted now

Answer (score 0):

`set()` does not have `.values()` method. If you want the length of the values, just use `df = len(postings[w])`

You will definitely get another error after solving this. That is:

```
score += query_weights[w] + postings[w].keys()
```

`set()` does not have `.keys()` method as well.